# In-App Purchases; Subscription Status Notification Retry

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Using In-App Purchases, Does the subscription status notification via Subscription status URL has a retry mechanism? That is if the receiving server is down what happens to the call made, is it lost? 

Apple documents for the same 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html